Property of the matrix operation to get reduced row echelon form?
If you have a matrix $A$, you can perform row operations to turn it into the reduced row echelon form $\hat{A}$.
I believe you can encode these row operations into a single matrix $R$ such that $RA = \hat{A}$ (I think? Correct me if I am wrong).
Are there any special properties of $R$ other than general matrix properties? For example, can we determine $\text{rank}(R)$ or is there any special property about the decompositions of $R$ (eigen decomposition, SVD, etc) as it relates to $A$ in any way?
One example... since $\text{rank}(RA) = \text{rank}(\hat{A}) = \text{rank}(A)$, this implies that $R$ must be invertible right? Since we don't know if $A$ is invertible or not, yet $\text{rank}(RA) = \text{rank}(A)$?
Another example... since $det(RA) = det(R)det(A) = det(\hat{A}) = {0\text{ or }1}$, this implies that $det(R) = \frac{1}{det(A)}$ when $A$ is full rank, right?

You might want to check the row operation matrices or elementary matrices.

Det only makes sense in the square case, of course.

$R$ is the product of the elementary matrices representing the row operations you carry out to get $A$ into reduced row echelon form. Every elementary matrix is invertible, so their product, $R$, is also invertible. Hence $\text{rank}(R) = n$ (assuming $A$ is $n\times n$). When $A$ is full rank, what you stated is correct.
I am unsure about properties relating to decomposition.
